# API endpoint doesnt return both columns selected from sql tables

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create an API endpoint that will show two columns from two different SQL tables using a primary key. While the query works in DB browser, in the API it only returns the second column selected (in this case sessions.name). Didn't find a similar problem to other APIs created and dont know how to make them both appear.

```
$query = "SELECT rooms.name, sessions.name 
              FROM sessions JOIN rooms 
              WHERE sessions.roomId = rooms.roomId";
```

Update (code from comment):

```
private function json_rooms() { 
    $query = "SELECT rooms.name, sessions.name FROM sessions JOIN rooms WHERE sessions.roomId = rooms.roomId"; 
    $params = []; 
    return ($this->recordset->getJSONRecordSet($query, $params)); 
}
```

Comment: please show the relevant php or javascript code that generates the output rather than just the sql.

Comment: This is the function used in PHP to get the data from the database. Rest of the website works fine. This is the bit that creates the problem:                                              private function json_rooms()
    {
        $query = "SELECT rooms.name, sessions.name FROM sessions JOIN rooms WHERE sessions.roomId = rooms.roomId";
        $params = [];
        return ($this->recordset->getJSONRecordSet($query, $params));
    }

Comment: Is it possible that your method `getJSONRecordSet` is to blame? It is tricky trying to problem solve when 1/2 the puzzle is missing as it were. If the query works fine in the db gui then the fault is not the sql - it must lie elesewhere?

Comment: Set aliases to the 2 columns so they don't have the same name `name`.

Comment: @forpas That did it. Thank you!